# Most Efficient way to store and process Huge Geo Spatial Data in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, gis

We need to store huge amounts of Geospatial data (Currently more then 1 billion events per day)

What's the most efficient way to store this data that can be worked on later in easy way for queries like Point in Polygon.

Currently we store it in hive partitioned by hour.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with hive?

Comment: The issue is compute. As i am just partitioning it on hour, hive has process all the data for queries like number of users in this polygon etc.   I want a mechanism to partition the data on user,time and location. so that the users close to each other are in the same partition.

Comment: So, one approach could be that you periodically run a series of hive query to create new final table (with new partition to keep all users in one) with data arranged in the way you want. And then keep on adding data into that table.

Comment: You can refer these slides :http://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/grailer-hochmuth-june27515pmroom212v3